# How to set variable maxValue in django forms

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-validation

I'm writing a code in django framework for a sales website and the number of available pieces of a certain merchandise is limited.
to obtain the number of remaining products I have to call a certain function.
Now I wanted to ask if there's any way to call this function in the models.py or forms.py modules or any other way to set this limit.

This is my view module:

```
from django.http.response import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import orderForm
from regpage.models import User
from django.views import View

class orderView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        form = orderForm()
        return render(request, "dashboard/order.html", {'form': form,})
```

This is my forms module:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Order

class orderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['productCount']
```

This is my models module:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.enums import Choices
from regpage.models import User
from django.core import validators
from django.core.validators import EmailValidator, MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator

class Order(models.Model):
    userID = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    productCount = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField() #THE LIMITED FIELD
```

This is my html file:

```
{% extends 'dashboard.html' %}

{% block dashTitle %}
    Order
{% endblock dashTitle %}


{% block dashContent %}
    <p style="text-align:center;font-size:30px;"><b> Order Page </b> </p>
    
    <form style="text-align:center;font-size:25px" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for field in form %}
            <div class="form-control {% if field.errors %}errors{% endif %}">
                {{ field.label_tag }}
                {{ field }}
                {{ field.errors }}
            </div>
            <br>
        {% endfor %}
        <br>
        <button type="submit">Order</button>    
    </form>
{% endblock dashContent %}
```

There's only one product in this website and one function should be called to obtain the number of remaining products.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try

```
class orderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    quantity = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.TextInput(
               attrs={
                    'min':0,
                    'value':0,
                    'type':'number',
               }))

    class Meta: 
        model = Order
        fields = ('__all__')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['productCount'].widget.attrs.update(
            {'max': self.instance.productCount},
        )
```